# In Perl, how can I write and read CSV file composed from a key and array?

Tags: perl, csv

I have a problem to write and read properly a CSV file composed of name(key) and array of values:

```
testarray.csv

foo1 ,0,0,0,0,1
foo2 ,1,0,0,0,1
foo3 ,3,4,5,6,7
.
.
.
```

I need to represent that file as follows:

`foo#` will be the key and the five following numbers will be its array.

What is the simple way to conduct that and to recall it for a use (not with Dumper)? How can I use a varible from an array of a specific key?

E.g.,

```
print $hsh{'foo1'}[4];
```

Comment: Are there spaces in the keys?

Comment: There's no reason giving that could make a YAML file useful advice, and it's a kneejerk response to suggest it. Very few things in the world understand YAML, but many of them understand CSV. There's no benefit with YAML in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, I would recommend [Text::xSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::xSV) and/or [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV) but for such simple data, a straightforward `join` should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
    foo1 => [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ],
    foo2 => [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 ],
    foo3 => [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ],
);

for my $key ( sort keys %hash ) {
    print join( q{,}, $key, @{ $hash{$key} } ), "\n";
}

__END__
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> ttt
foo1,0,0,0,0,1
foo2,1,0,0,0,1
foo3,3,4,5,6,7
```

Reading it in:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    last unless /\S/;
    my ($key, @data) = split /,/;
    $hash{$key} = \@data;
}

print $hash{foo2}->[4], "\n";

__DATA__
foo1,0,0,0,0,1
foo2,1,0,0,0,1
foo3,3,4,5,6,7
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> ttt
1
```

Answer (score 4):

[Sinan Unur's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104038/in-perl-how-can-i-write-and-read-csv-file-composed-from-a-key-and-array/1104057#1104057) is good and correct, but I think that the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135671/yohad)'s problem is an [XY Problem](http://perlmonks.org/?node=xy+problem).  He is specifically asking about reading and storing data from a CSV file.  Since that seems to be the real goal, then the best solution is to make use of reuse and get [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.12/lib/Text/CSV.pm) installed in your Perl.  It does the heavy lifting of dealing with CSV files, gives you ways to reference all the data, and provides a nice API while doing so.

If that doesn't float your boat, you can try [DBD::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~jzucker/DBD-CSV-0.22/lib/DBD/CSV.pm) which, in conjunction with [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.609/DBI.pm) will give you the ability to use SQL to query/insert/update the CSV.  If you're used to SQL, that is a nifty way to proceed as well.

Edit:

Based on simple nature of data, if you really want to roll your own, his solution is a good one, already gave it +1.